# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE in line 61

Tags: php

I seem to have an error in line the following line but i cant figure it out, i'm new at this:

```
<input type="submit" value="<?php _e( 'Download Export File', 'yit' ) ?>" class="button-secondary" id="export-file" />
```

Thanks

Comment: Nothing is wrong with this particular line. Look at nearby code.

Comment: @Mike, there is, check Shankar's answer.

Comment: @Nikola: Negative, [the closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php).

Comment: Although, see kelly's comment on Shankar's answer.. he says now it works.. Any reason for that if semicolon is not needed? Old version of PHP? On the php website it doesn't say since when it is not necessary.

Comment: @Mike, That does not implies to functions , `echo` is a language construct.

Comment: @Nikola I believe the actual error must be elsewhere. I can't reproduce it by omitting the semicolon: http://ideone.com/bLEYIc.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: There is no `echo` in the posted code.

Comment: @Mike, That's why it required a semicolon.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran My bad, I misread your comment. Still, whether a construct or a function it does not make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put a semicolon here

```
<?php _e( 'Download Export File', 'yit' ); ?>
                                    -----^
```